# how to list binary numbers java

Tags: java, binary

How do you make a list of binary numbers? The variables do not accept zeros when initializing. It only adds the numbers. I am trying to get the binary numbers into a list while incrementing them such as 00000000,00000001,00000010,00000011, 00000110, 00000111....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int index = 00000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
    if(i < 10)
    {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.print(index++);
    }
    else {
    System.out.print(index);
    }
    if(i > 10 && i < 100)
    {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.print(index++);
    }
    else {
    System.out.print(index);
    }   
    }
    }
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: If you want the binary number strings in a `List<String>`, why are you printing? Where is your list?

Comment: I know how to make the list. I do not know how to loop the binary numbers by adding 1 to it since it has 0's in the beginning of the binary numbers.

Comment: If you want *binary* numbers, why are you checking against `10` and `100`, which are decimal numbers, and have nothing whatsoever to do with binary numbers?

Comment: `String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(1)).replace(' ', '0')` - just use [.toBinaryString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) like this for padded zeros.

Comment: Thank you Harshal; does that remove the zeros? I need the zeros. However, how can I increment the binary digits?

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 256).mapToObj(n -> String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(n)).replace(' ', '0')).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'));
}
```

Outputs:

```
00000001
00000010
00000011
00000100
00000101
00000110
00000111
00001000
00001001
00001010
```

Read more on [.toBinaryString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)).

---

Get it into a list as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646319/how-to-list-binary-numbers-java/61646598#comment109045109_61646319):

```
List<String> binaryNums = IntStream.range(0, 256)
    .mapToObj(n -> String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(n))
    .replace(' ', '0')).collect(Collectors.toList());
```